# Javascript location.href not being recognized in PHP echo

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to get `onclick="javascript:location.href='where.ever'` to work in a php echo so I'm able to click on the entire row when a dropdown displays.

I have the following code:

```
echo "<div class='dropdown-item-row row' onclick='javascript:location.href='" . $row['username'] . "'>
            <div class='dd-pic'>
                <a href='" . $row['username'] . "'>
                    <img src='" . $row['profile_pic'] ."'>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class='dd-right'>
                <div class='dd-title'>
                    <a href='" . $row['username'] . "'>" . $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'] . "</a>
                </div>
                <div class='dd-user-url'>
                    <a href='" . $row['username'] . "'>" . $row['username'] ."</a>
                </div>
                <p class='dd-common-friends'>" . $mutual_friends ."</p>
            </div>
        </div>";
```

The other `<a>` tags are recognized, but I'd like to make these so they are not even necessary.  Ideally, I'd like to just click the row and that's the link.  I'm not sure why the php echo is not recognizing the `onclick`

```
<div class='dropdown-item-row row' onclick='javascript:location.href='" . $row['username'] . "'>
```

Is there something wrong with the way I've expressed it in the echo?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always look at the resulting output. Your output looks like this:

```
<div class='dropdown-item-row row' onclick='javascript:location.href='where.ever''>
```

Which you can clearly see is invalid with the quotes there. (Also, side-note `javascript:` is used in `href` attributes, not in inline event handlers)

---

Why not just have your entire row be an `<a>` tag?

```
?>
<a href="<?=$row['username']?>" class="dropdown-item-row row">
    <div.....
    .....>
</a>
<?php
```

Also you might find things tidier if you drop out of PHP mode to output HTML. Use `<?=$something?>` to pop back into PHP mode to output a value. This technique also generally colour-codes better in IDEs!

Comment: I tried using an <a> tage around the whole div, but it doesn't work either.  The echo is being dropped into another div however, could this be the problem?

Comment: I don't know, but you don't need JavaScript at all here.